# How to compare rows show the reason of uniqueness in new column?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-cleaning, data-comparison

I have the following data:

|  | Name | Age | Country | Occupation | Hobby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Fishing |
| 1 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Gardening |
| 2 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Fishing |
| 3 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Reading |
| 4 | B | 15 | SW | Job holder | Fishing |
| 5 | B | 15 | SW | Job holder | Playing |
| 6 | C | 23 | DD | Job holder | Coding |
| 7 | B | 23 | AA | Job holder | Fishing |
| 8 | D | 34 | GH | Job holder | Fishing |
| 9 | D | 33 | TR | Other | Fishing |

When there is a duplicate in the "Name" columns, I would like to compare them and I would like to know the reason for their uniqueness. I want to add one new column which column should contain the responsible column header names for this uniqueness. If a row is found one time then write 'Unique' in the reason column.

The output should look like this:

|  | Name | Age | Country | Occupation | Hobby | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Fishing | Occupation, Hobby |
| 1 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Gardening | Occupation, Hobby |
| 2 | A | 23 | DE | Student | Fishing | Occupation, Hobby |
| 3 | A | 23 | DE | Job holder | Reading | Occupation, Hobby |
| 4 | B | 15 | SW | Job holder | Fishing | Hobby |
| 5 | B | 15 | SW | Job holder | Playing | Hobby |
| 6 | C | 23 | DD | Job holder | Coding | Unique |
| 7 | B | 23 | AA | Job holder | Fishing | Age, Country |
| 8 | D | 34 | GH | Job holder | Fishing | Age, Country, Occupation |
| 9 | D | 33 | TR | Other | Fishing | Age, Occupation, Occupation |

I trying this way:

*`dif = [i for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(df.loc[0].values, df.loc[9,:].values)) if x!=y ] df.iloc[:, dif]`*

but it's not giving the way output should look like. I am new in python, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that your provided example is incorrect according to your logic. There are 3 B rows which should be handled together. If this is not the case, you can update my solutions below by grouping over the consecutive values instead of the values themselves (or a different logic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the non-unique reasons, then merge as a string.

There are multiple ways to do this.

Using [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and dot product:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Name').nunique()
df['Reason'] = df['Name'].map(df2.gt(1).dot(df2.columns+', ')
                                 .str[:-2].replace('', 'Unique'))
```

With `groupby.nunique` and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df2 = df.melt('Name')
df['Reason'] = (df['Name']
                .map(df2.groupby(['Name', 'variable'], as_index=False)['value'].nunique()
                        .query('value > 1').groupby('Name')['variable'].agg(', '.join))
                .fillna('Unique')
               )
```

With [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['Reason'] = df['Name'].map(df.groupby('Name')
                                .apply(lambda g: ', '.join(g.columns[g.nunique().gt(1)]))
                                .replace('', 'Unique')
                             )
```

Output:

```
  Name  Age Country  Occupation      Hobby                    Reason
0    A   23      DE  Job holder    Fishing         Occupation, Hobby
1    A   23      DE  Job holder  Gardening         Occupation, Hobby
2    A   23      DE     Student    Fishing         Occupation, Hobby
3    A   23      DE  Job holder    Reading         Occupation, Hobby
4    B   15      SW  Job holder    Fishing       Age, Country, Hobby
5    B   15      SW  Job holder    Playing       Age, Country, Hobby
6    C   23      DD  Job holder     Coding                    Unique
7    B   23      AA  Job holder    Fishing       Age, Country, Hobby
8    D   34      GH  Job holder    Fishing  Age, Country, Occupation
9    D   33      TR       Other    Fishing  Age, Country, Occupation
```